# Marklogic Machine Learning or NLP - Natural Language processing

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Which API should we use for NLP (Natural Language processing). does Marklogic have support for same with in it. is there any sample program available on github as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a built-in NLP capability. That said, MarkLogic is a fantastic platform upon which to build NLP tools. Document enrichment using NLP certainly allows for far more robust search applications and such.

There are third-party tools out there from a few different companies that may suit your needs. Take a look at Expert System and SmartLogic. There may be others that I'm not thinking of at the moment.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. Does that actually mean that one can use, say Apache Spark connection or build NodeJS(or Java?) NLP applications explicitly on top of MarkLogic?

Comment: That is my understanding. I haven't personally done it, but I know there is a Spark Connector available, though still under development. There is also a Hadoop Connector. There's links at developer.marklogic.com to get more information, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Will give it a shot